# calling a trim method in actionscript 2.0

Tags: actionscript

Hi I Got a notnull function for a text field as below

```
private function valStringNotNull( val:String ) :Boolean
    {
        if ( String(val).length <= 0 )
        {
            _errorCode = "StringNull";
            return false;
        }

        _errorCode = "NoError";
        return true;
    }
```

and this function is being called here

```
var pCnt:Number = 0;
  _validateParams[pCnt++] = { type: "notNull",  input: win.firstNameInput , isSendData:true, dataName:"firstName"};
  _validateParams[pCnt++] = { type: "notNull",  input: win.lastNameInput, isSendData:true, dataName:"lastName"};
  _validateParams[pCnt++] = { type: "noValidation", input: roleCombo, isSendData:true, dataName:"role" };

  Selection.setFocus(win.firstNameInput);
```

and for the not null I defined this way

```
private function validateCases ( param:Object ) :Boolean
 {
  _errorObj = param.input || param.input1;
  switch( param.type )
  {
                 case "notNull":
    return valStringNotNull( param.input.text );
   break;
                       }
 }
```

but as you see as I defined the length should be greater than zero its taking even a space as an input and displaying blank white space in my text field so I got a trim function as below

```
public function ltrim(input:String):String
    {
        var size:Number = input.length;
        for(var i:Number = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(input.charCodeAt(i) > 32)
            {
                return input.substring(i);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

and I need to call this trim function before my not null function so that it trims off all the leftside white space but as I am very new to flash can some one help me how to keep this trim function before the notnull function.Can some one please help me with this please

Answer (score 1):

A function to replace any string as you wish, just combine them!

```
String.prototype.replace = function(searchStr, replaceStr):String 
{
return this.split(searchStr).join(replaceStr);
};

Example:
// initial string with a placeholder
var str:String = '$person is welcome';
// replace $person with 'Flash developer' and trace it
var replacedStr:String = str.replace('$person','Flash developer');
trace(replacedStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change valStringNotNull() as follows?

```
private function valStringNotNull( val:String ) :Boolean
{
    if ( String(ltrim(val)).length <= 0 )
    {
            _errorCode = "StringNull";
            return false;
    }

    _errorCode = "NoError";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: sorry this is stackoverflow is trimming off the spaces right now its displaying NAME:------John but I need some thing like NAME:John chopping the extra white spaces please consider "-" as a white space and please help me